# trying to make multi classifications with flutter and tflite package

Tags: flutter

```
 List? outputs;
  String? brainResult;
  late double confidence;
  classifyImage( image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
    ).then((value){
      print("predict = "+value.toString());
      outputs = value;
      confidence=value![0]["confidence"];
      if(value[0]["index"]==0){
        brainResult="Positive Brain tumor";
      }
      else{
        brainResult="Nigative Brain tumor";
      }
      emit(ClassificationSuccess());
    }).catchError((error){
      print("Error of class is ${error.toString()}");
    });
  }
```

> this function to make classify

---

```
 List<Media> selectedimages=[];
  void selectImages()  {
    Future _listImagePaths =  ImagePickers.pickerPaths(
        galleryMode: GalleryMode.image,
        selectCount: 5,
        showGif: false,
        showCamera: true,
        compressSize: 500,
        uiConfig: UIConfig(uiThemeColor: Color(0xffff0f50)),
        cropConfig: CropConfig(enableCrop: false, width: 2, height: 1)).then((value){
       value.forEach((element) { 
         classifyImage(element);
       });   
    });
  }
```

> this function to get images and make classify

---

i get this error for all picture except last one

```
PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
```

> > while select 2 picture

> I/flutter ( 2193): Error of class is PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy   
> I/flutter ( 2193):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.(TflitePlugin.java:450)
> I/flutter ( 2193):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.(TflitePlugin.java:488)
> I/flutter ( 2193):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:105)
> I/flutter ( 2193):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
> I/flutter ( 2193): predict = [{confidence: 0.8329743146896362, index: 0, label: 0 yes}, {confidence: 0.16702567040920258, index: 1, label: 1 no}]